# removing day portion of date variable for time series SAS

Tags: date, format, sas, forecasting

I'm having some frustration with dates in SAS.
I am using proc forecast and am trying make my dates spread evenly.  I did some pre-processing wiht proc sql to get my counts by month but my dates are incorrect.

Though my dataset looks good (b/c I used format MONYY.) the actual value of that variable is wrong.

```
date   year month count
Jan10  2010 1     100
Feb10  2010 2     494
...
..
.
```

The Date value is actually the full SAS representation of the date (18267), meaning that it includes the day count.

Do I  need to convert the variable to a string and back to a date or is there a quick proc i can run?

My goal is to use the date variable with proc forecast so I only want Month and year.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the problem that the data are on different days, but the same month (ie, you have a row with Jan1 and a row with Jan15), or are they all on the first of the month (or similar) and it's just that there are different numbers of days per month?  Perhaps add the `gplot` code with a working example dataset (and proc forecast code if that's needed) to show what you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 2):

You can't define a date variable in SAS (so the number of days passed from 1jan1960) excluding the day.
What you can do is to hide the day with a format like monyy. but the underlying number will always contain that information.

Maybe you can use the `interval=month` option in proc forecast?

Please add some detail about the problem you're encountering with the forecast procedure.

---

EDIT: check [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/ets/ex_code/121/forgs.html) example:

```
data past;
   keep date sales;
   format date monyy5.;
   lu = 0;
   n = 25;
   do i = -10 to n;
      u = .7 * lu + .2 * rannor(1234);
      lu = u;
      sales = 10 + .10 * i + u;
      date = intnx( 'month', '1jul1991'd, i - n );
      if i > 0 then output;
   end;
run;
proc forecast data=past interval=month lead=10 out=pred;
   var sales;
   id date;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look.  My issue is actually using the date variable in regards to plotting via gplot.  The PROC FORECAST does its work via interval = month, but when I plot actuals and forecast it says "WARNING: The intervals on the axis labeled CREATION_DATE2 are not evenly spaced.
WARNING: No minor tick marks will be drawn because major tick increments have been specified in uneven or unordered intervals."